# select node type in eclipse.jdt.core AST for external object

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, lombok, eclipse-jdt, ellipse

If we create an object from a class and then call a method on it at compile time and add it to the AST tree, what kind of nodes should we use?

for example: `new PasswordFormate().format();`

**What is the type of this node in the AST?**

**What is the type of children of this node in AST?**

Comment: Please rephrase your question a bit, so it becomes clearer what exactly belongs to what. Is the class of the object you want to create the class file being compiled? What do you want to 'add it to the AST'? What is 'it' in this case? Is new `PasswordFormate` also being compiled, or is that already compiled and part of the compiler? Also, what do you expect your output code to look like (what would the file look like, if it already contained what you want to add)?

Comment: in lombok project we have a functional interface in the library and each class can implement this interface,
then we give this class in annotation which implements the format method for the field 
to be formatted in the toString method.                    @ToString.Format(className.class)
private String password;
An object of this class is then created and the format method is called on it 
and is injected in the toString method in compile time. @TreffnonX

Comment: So the result of the method call already works, and you get (a String?) object back, and now you want to know how to integrate the resulting string in the toString, via an AST-morph? The answer to that is: It depends on *how* the toString method should look like afterwards. I would manually write it for an example class, and then invoke the compiler and use it to print the example methods AST. Then you can see directly what the AST needs to look like, if the method already contained what you want to 'inject'. By the way, it is not injection you are doing, it is AST-transformation.

Comment: Yes, thank you, In fact, "new PasswordFormat.format()" is inserted into the toString method at compile time until the toString method is called, so the format method is also called and the result is displayed inside the toStirng.I do not know the type of node and the type of children of this node in the parser tree to work properly. @TreffnonX

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out how an AST 'looks like' by implementing an ASTVisitor. ASTVisitors have a method called `preVisit` (and `postVisit`) which you can use to print an AST in any form you like (e.g. the classes of the respective ASTNode-Object).

Take a look at this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

I would go about it by implementing the ASTVisitor with the two methods mentioned above and printing a tree as String. Then you can see what ASTNode classes are used.

To launch your implemented AST-visitor, use the visit method:

```java
ASTParser astParser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8); // Or use whatever constant applies here
astParser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
astParser.setSource(unit);
astParser.setResolveBindings(true); // maybe false, depending on your use case?
CompilationUnit compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) astParser.createAST(null);
ASTVisitor astPrintingVisitor = new ASTPrinter(); // you need to implement this
compilationUnit.visit(astPrintingVisitor);
```